# Hadoop Block Count Calculation

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

We are running a Hadoop cluster with replication factor as 3 and block size as 64MB. We just wanted to know the best way to calculate/run command for seeing actual data size that resides across the datanodes.
Also, we tried using `hdfs dfs -du -h` and `hdfs dfs dfsreport -report`, but what we noticed was that if our disk size is 12TB:
a) The first command would show me the data usage to be close to 500GB
b) The second command would show the data usage at 11.5TB.

What is the reason for difference that we are missing here? Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I want to correct you with the 2nd command you mentioned. It is:

```
hdfs dfsadmin -report
```

Coming to the point why the results are different. Now, `du` command shows only the data used on dfs not the non-dfs used. On the other hand the 2nd command calculates the total space(dfs+non-dfs) and then gives you the detail of total data used.

It also carries the replicated amount of data, i.e if the data consuming 5 TB space and replication is 3 then dfs-used will be 15 TB.

Hope that clears your query.